# When I upload my file using Rails app on Phusion Passenger, it gets permission 600

Tags: apache-2.4, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger

I have the Rails server setup using Apache and Phusion Passenger. As per their documentation, I have created a user specific to that app. This user has root access.

When a file is uploaded via the app, it gets resized and everything, the files exists on the server, but their permissions are set to `600`. How can I change this default permission?

**Update**

When I do `umask` on the ssh, I get `022`. And when I create a file using the bash, the permission on that file is `644`. This `600` only happens for files uploaded via `Ajax` to the server.

Comment: Include what umask settings are in use for more assistance.

Comment: Sorry where do I find that information? My environemnt is Ubuntu